# Search and replace whitespace with string and eliminate character push

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to find a string in a specific space within my document and then "pull back" the text on the line so that it eliminates whitespace resulting from the "push" after replacement.

In this instance, the text string I need will replace eight spaces of white space with literally `000.0000`. Of course, this will push the remainder of the line up eight spaces. So I need the expression to pull the remainder of each line back eight spaces.

This is very uniform. The spaces the string will occupy are 192 through 199.

Here's an example as requested. Note that a certain identifier has been replaced with "xxxxxxxxx" for security purposes:

```
2016102012403654725200509261112005100000000201109081004010700000006210206731030F43.21                                                                                                          F43.21  0100000000006      60009998    9998    9998    0000ENG6201505110000000010000960
```

The correct line would look like this:

```
2016102012xxxxxxxxx195209141112001100000000201210291012020800000006220301301010000.0000                                                                                                        <000.0000>0000000000006      6000070811439998    9998    0000ENG6201212200000000010000100
```

The angle brackets are not to be taken literally. They are merely to highlight the string I would like to place in, while removing the whitespace. Of course, the purpose is to also bring the remainder of the line back eight characters, as stated earlier

Comment: can you make an example, BEFORE what you have, and AFTER what do you want? P.S, the code block can help you format the example.

Comment: "Replace" (as in `:substitute/pat/repl`) already removes the original match (unlike insering with `i`). If you replace 8 spaces with `000.0000`, the overall length of the line will be kept.

Comment: Sure! Please note that a particular identifier has been replaced with "xxxxxxxxx" for security purposes.  Here is the line before the "000.0000" is added. If you were to paste it into Vim or a text editor, you'd see that the  white space begins on 192 and ends on 199:

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Kent. Sorry I didn't have a direct example before, I've just posted one.

Comment: Sato Katsura, that's a great answer. How do I do this globally? I guess I should've asked that before.

Comment: Umm, like any other global replacement?

Comment: I was going to credit you with your answer, but I've changed my mind. Thanks for what good you actually did though, Sato. I actually do appreciate that.

Comment: Ok, deleting my answer then. _shrug_

Comment: I've got a copy. SHRUG.

Comment: @Galidari - instead of commenting on not crediting Sato Katsura for his answer it would have been more helpfull to let him/us know what was wrong with it so a solution could have been worked out. Perhaps you didn't mean it the way it sounds but your comment actually got me fired up. If it has the same effect on other readers, you are not likely to get much help soon.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers...well, it was kind of rude the way he answered back. I even told him I was grateful for his help. This is the thing I hate about this community. If a person get's slighted and they react in a relatively peaceful way, somebody gets "fired up" and then wags their finger at the person who got slighted. Not very good form. This is why I hate coming here. Believe me, my friend, it is ALWAYS a last resort for me to come to SO. Sorry that you were offended, but then it really wasn't your discussion, now was it?

Comment: @Galidari - I can see how that might have looked to you and in retrospect, I'm biased because Sato's answers helped me in the past. I'm pretty sure it wasn't *meant* to be rude. Sorry to hear that SO is your last resort though. For me, it's my first but it seems more people are having the same feeling about SO as you do so there's definitely an issue that needs to be resolved... I have for the life of me no idea how though.

Comment: *and btw, as you for your last comment: it removed any negativity I felt initially. It also placed the burden upon us, the community ;)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I really appreciate the understanding. To be completely honest, I really would LIKE for SO to be my FIRST resort. There were some things I had to learn from a posting I made a few weeks ago and I had to read through the rules and guidelines to get a better understanding as to the actual purpose of SO. But they can't really govern how someone answers a question always and that's something that's completely understandable. Programmers, engineers and techs aren't always the warmest of people and sometimes they get questions that come across as dumb. Mine may have been dumb.